# Android layout folder name for Nexus 5 mobile

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to design an android layout for nexus 5 mobile and need to give a fixed width/height. After searching with many websites I have used the layout folder named as "layout-normal-xxhdi". It works perfectly for nexus 5 but unfortunately it will affect other mobiles. Ex) I tried with moto e it also takes the layout file from "res/layout-normal-xxhdpi.xml" folder. Please someone give the exact layout folder name for nexus5.

**My layout folders,**
res/layout.xml
res/layout-normal-xxhdpi.xml

**Note:**
For other mobiles it will need to take the layout file from "res/layout.xml"

Comment: AFAIK you cannot set layouts according to device. `layout-normal-xxhdi` is based on screen resolutions.

Comment: Is there any possible way to do this...............

Comment: nope. Although you can add [Support Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) and [Compatible Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) in manifest to limit devices you can install your app on

Comment: Thanks Murtaza Khursheed Hussain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with folder name. But you could try to recognize the device model (here Nexus 5) in your Java code and use the appropriate layout. To do that, you could use [Build.MODEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL).

Comment: For this approach, I need to check the device name and based on that I need to switch the layout file right. Is it affecting the device performance?. So I'm going to store the build model in final static variable then only it will call the Build.MODEL one times.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Looking at the source code of the Build class, the MODEL field is already static final. It shouldn't have an impact on your application performance.

Comment: Thanks  Gaëtan...I can't able to make this answer as correct because i need more stackoverflow reputation points, sorry for that. Will try this..

Answer (score 0):

Testing in AS v1.5 using the default Nexus 5 emulator (selected replicate device during creation), you can almost specifically target Nexus 5's specs using the "**sw384dp-xxhdpi**" folder name.